# Unable to return JSON response to client using Node

Tags: json, node.js, http, httprequest

I am having trouble returning a JSON object back to a client upon request - I am just working with the first GET call to '/btc'.

```
//Main server to recieve requests
http.createServer(function(req,res){

 switch(req.method){
      case 'GET':
           switch(req.url){
                case '/btc':
                     callBtcApi(req,res)
                     console.log(' btc called');
                     break;
                case '/wallet':
                     callBtcWallet(req,res)
                     console.log('wallet called');
                     break;
                case '/weather':
                     callWeather(req,res);
                     console.log('weather called');
                     break
                default:
                     console.log('calling but not hitting');
                     break;
           }
      case 'POST':
           switch(req.url){
                case '/update':
                     console.log('update called');
                     break;
           }
 }

}).listen(3000);
```

callBtcApi() below, queries a bitcoin API and returns a JSON object successfully (I do intend to do more with the function, just getting the basics down first). callBtcApi() is successfully being called.

```
function callBtcApi(req,res){

message = '';

 https.get('https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/global/GBP/', function(res){
      res.on('data',function(data){
           message += data;
      });
      res.on('end',function(){
           console.log('props called ;)');
           writeToCLient(res,message);
      });
 }).on('error', function(e){
      console.error(e);
 });
}
```

The issue I am having is when I then pass this data to my writeToCLient() function in res.on('end'). The error i receive in the terminal is

```
TypeError: res.setHeader is not a function
```

I know the message is passed into the function writeToCLient() as I am able to see the data in the terminal when I console.log(message) if I temporarurly hide all of the res.() calls.

```
function writeToCLient(res,message){
 console.log(message);
 res.statusCode = 200;
 res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
 res.end(JSON.stringify(message));
}
```

I have searched google but haven't found anything that explains what could be the issue. Is the issue possibly down to calling a HTTP.get() request from inside callBtcApi() which is sitting inside my main server? 
Thanks

Comment: You're passing the wrong response object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try with this?

```
function callBtcApi(request,response){

message = '';
 https.get('https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/global/GBP/', function(res){
      res.on('data',function(data){
           message += data;
      });
      res.on('end',function(){
           console.log('props called ;)');
           writeToCLient(response,message);
      });
 }).on('error', function(e){
      console.error(e);
 });
}
```

Comment: Thats perfect thanks LuisPinto. As SLaks had said regarding the response object, was that the reason for the issue? Was the callBtcApi() function building over the main server response object? Hope that makes sense, I am just trying to understand where I went wrong.

Comment: Yes, It was that you were passing the res object from `https.get`instead of from `callBtcApi`because the variable res was being overwritten. So you only need to change the variable names ;)